# CountdownTimer is running after loop is finished in Flutter

Tags: flutter, nested-loops, countdowntimer

I'm trying to build an application which requires a countdown to show time to the user how much time is left. But the loop is not working as I was expecting.

```
for(int i=0;i<widget.sets;i++)
      {
        while(j<5){
          CountdownTimer(Duration(seconds: 2), Duration(seconds: 1)).listen((data){
          })..onData((data){
            print(data.elapsed.inSeconds.toString());
          })..onDone((){
            print('onDone.........');
          });
          print('Hello');
          j++;
        }
        j=0;
        print((i+1).toString());
      }
```

I got this output

> flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: Hello
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 1
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........
>       flutter: 2
>       flutter: onDone.........

The output I was expecting Is

```
flutter: 1
flutter: 4
flutter: 3
flutter: 4
flutter: 5
flutter: onDone.........
flutter: Hello
flutter: 1
flutter: 4
flutter: 3
flutter: 4
flutter: 5
flutter: onDone.........
flutter: Hello
```

And So on..
How to make this code work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because all the timers in your loop are created simultaneously, so then every second they print the same value.

Maybe you should use asynchronous suspension at some point, something like `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1));`

Comment: I already tried this. The problem I'm facing right now is the next Timer is started before first ends.

Comment: @Creator Yeah, that's because you add them all simultaneously in for loop. Maybe you should instead of the for loop write some method, that will create next timer only after previous fires up.